# xcopy from online storage

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

Is there any way to copy some files from an internal online storage to a local drive by using a *.bat-file on Windows XP?
Due to some strange internal restrictions I am only allowed to use a *.bat-file to do this.
The path to the files, which are to be copied, is kinda "http://files.in-house/section/linkages"

So I tried xcopy (xcopy goto.in-house/section/linkages U:\linkages) in any variations, with quotation marks, without etc. but it does not work
a) is there any way to do this?
b) how?

Comment: This should be removed to superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to a question asked on SuperUser.com, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/59465/is-it-possible-to-download-using-the-windows-command-line). The [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/59489) uses vbscript, which is not installed in all WinXP systems. To check if you have it, just type `cscript` at a command line prompt. If you need to download it, it's [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8247).

The number two answer relies on `bitsadmin`, which is not part of XP, but can be obtained with the [Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18546).